# where can I add - allprojects repositories in gradle.build file android

Tags: android

allprojects {
repositories {
...
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
}

I want to add a new dependency in gradle.build file but don't know where to add this section

Answer (score -1):

There are usually two build.gradle files - one in the root folder of your project, and one in the app module (also any other modules you might have). You should add the above snippet within the root build.gradle file, for example:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```